# How to check Polyline Hierarchy in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, line, topology

I want to check polyline Ascending order hierarchy for road network in QGIS, For example 
Grade 1 road must start from Grade 0, 
Grade 2 road must start from Grade 1, 
Grade 3 road must start from Grade 2

If not tool should mark an error. Is there any plugin or extension available for what I want exactly?